# How can I remove emojis from a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, emoji

I know that

```py
test = []
for item in my_texts:
    test.append(item.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'))
```

removes emojis from a list. But how can I remove emojis from a dataframe? When I try

```py
a = []
for item in goldtest['Text']:
    a.append(item.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'))
```

I get only the last entry of goldtest. When I try the code on the whole dataframe, I get ''AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'encode'''

Comment: a DataFrame is not a string. So ask yourself what it is that you are actually calling `encode`, as your error suggests its a DataFrame

Comment: And this pattern will not only remove "emoji"s, but all accented characters, non latin letters, and punctuation signs beside a few of the more common ones - effectively corrupting any text data you have.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would be the equivalent code for pandas. It operates column by column.

```
df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii'))
```

Comment: With my data this gives me an AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', 'occurred at index Index'). Meaning one value in Index is a comma?

Comment: Try now, I edited it to coerce all the values to str

Comment: Thanks for your vote. Next time it will be much more useful if you can add a simple reproducible example :D

Comment: Works good, but unfortunately also delates all polish special characters like ą, ę, ń, ó, ż... Do you know how to overcome it?

Comment: Tried with a DF with multiple columns specifying desired column. Threw the error ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str' ```. Tried to recreate setting described here with DF with 1 column. Still same error message. Text is in German. Instead of investigating further used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65109065/python-pandas-remove-emojis-from-dataframe/65109987#65109987)  from xjcl. Worked without tweaking

Answer (score 2):

You can use [emoji](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/) package:

```py
import emoji
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'str_data':['يااا واجعوط هذا راه باغي يبدع فالسانكيام‍♀️']})
df['str_data'] = df['str_data'].apply(lambda s: emoji.replace_emoji(s, ''))
df
```

Output:

| str_data |
| --- |
| يااا واجعوط هذا راه باغي يبدع فالسانكيام |

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all special characters including emojis except letters and numbers from a given Column

```
goldtest['Text'] = goldtest['Text'].str.replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]', '', flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: It works. Just a quick note - it will also replace space with '', thus merging text. Make sure to change '' to ' ' so you still have spaces between words