# Python pandas: Remove emojis from DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, emoji

I have a dataframe which contains a lot of different emojis and I want to remove them. I looked at answers to similar questions but they didn't work for me.

```
index| messages
----------------
1    |Hello!  
2    |Good Morning   
3    |How are you ?
4    | Good 
5    | Ländern
```

Now I want to remove all these emojis from the DataFrame so it looks like this

```
    index| messages
    ----------------
    1    |Hello!
    2    |Good Morning   
    3    |How are you ?
    4    | Good 
    5    |Ländern
```

I tried the solution here but unfortunately it also removes all non-English letters like "ä"
[How can I remove emojis from a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57514169/how-can-i-remove-emojis-from-a-dataframe)

Comment: Please paste the dataframe as-is from the output/console. Don't format it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217909/removing-all-emojis-from-text#52571541

Comment: @Vishnudev Unfortiantly I am not allowed to share the acual dataframe, that's why I formated it

Comment: I meant the sample itself, dont put `-` or `|`

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. (it's my first time posting a question so I didn't know how to write it)

Comment: @Moe: Hi Moe, please put the "ä" character in your data example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing all Emojis from Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217909/removing-all-emojis-from-text)

Comment: @RuthgerRighart I had it in the last line as one of the things why the solution in the given link didn't work but I added it now, thank you for the remark.

Comment: I found an existing answer here which might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57514515/14718928

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution that will keep all ASCII and latin-1 characters, i.e. characters between U+0000 and U+00FF in [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). For extended Latin plus Greek, use `< 1024`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'messages': ['Länder ❤️', 'Hello! ']})

filter_char = lambda c: ord(c) < 256
df['messages'] = df['messages'].apply(lambda s: ''.join(filter(filter_char, s)))
```

Result:

```
  messages
0  Länder 
1  Hello!
```

Note this does not work for Japanese text for example. Another problem is that the heart "emoji" is actually a [Dingbat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat#Dingbats_Unicode_block) so I can't simply filter for the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block#List_of_blocks) of Unicode, oh well.

Comment: Works well, extra credits for the flag ;-)

Comment: Thank you a lot this worked for me (Vielen Dank)

Comment: If this doesn't work for some cases, you can also try `filter(lambda c: c.isalpha(), s)` -- that should handle Japanese for example. But it does filter `!` -- oh well.

Comment: We are not suppose to assign lambda expression to variable.  `df['messages'] = df['messages'].apply(lambda s: ''.join(filter(lambda c: ord(c) < 256, s)))`  will be correct one.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following is answering your question. I added some other characters for verification.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'messages':['Hello! ', 'Good-Morning ', 'How are you ?', ' Goodé ', 'Ländern' ]})

df['messages'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.encode('latin-1', 'ignore').decode('latin-1'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [emoji](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/) package:

```py
import emoji

df = ...
df['messages'] = df['messages'].apply(lambda s: emoji.replace_emoji(s, ''))
```