# How to remove images from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a file that contains people's first and last names. The names are entered by the user, and it is basically free format (not in my control to restrict the input values allowed). This has resulted in entries like the following:

[image]

With the exception of row 12, all the other entries have issues with additional "images" (not even sure that is the right term) being entered in the field.

Obviously using ord() to replace them with nothing is not possible, as is will strip away large amounts of valid characters, such as the Chinese script, and other languages that do not use the roman alphabet.

Is there a way to strip these "images" from the field, without removing valid characters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51784964/remove-emojis-from-multilingual-unicode-text/51785357#51785357).

Comment: this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57514169/how-can-i-remove-emojis-from-a-dataframe

Comment: Are they actually emojis?